# JavaMailSender sending mail with Kubernetes PodName

Tags: java, spring-boot, email, kubernetes

I am using following properties in application.properties

```
spring.mail.host=${SPRING_MAIL_HOST:smtp.gmail.com}
spring.mail.port=${SPRING_MAIL_PORT:587}
spring.mail.username=${SPRING_MAIL_USERNAME:myemail@gmail.com}
spring.mail.password=${SPRING_MAIL_PASSWORD:password}
```

But I am getting mail from Kubernetes Pod Name as **root@uat-workflow-engine-5957795d66-chjlq.**
I haven't set any such property in environment setEnv file.

Why I am not getting mail from username mentioned in application.properties.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.from=myemail@gmail.com
```